# Scaling a RigidBody during Runtime

Tags: reactjs, collision-detection, physics, rigid-bodies, rapier

I am trying to re-create a little game called orbital (just for fun). In this game the player shoots a circle into an arena. This circle stops somewhere in the arena and expands in size until it collides with the arena border or another circle. (See picture below)

[Orbital game overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rfvz4.jpg)

The issue I have, is that when the circle is expanding, the Rigid-body applied to the circle does not increase in size. It just keeps the size it had when I first created the Rigid-Body.

So the question: How can I cause a re-render of the rigid-body or update its size dynamically?
I am using React-Three-Fiber and Rapier JS.

Currently I tried to set the initial size of the circle using the "args" property and then change the size using the "scale" property on the rigid-body. "scale" is using "state" so it does update the shape, just not the rigid body...

Here's my code so you can better understand what I am trying to tell you

```
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { RigidBody } from "@react-three/rapier";



const Obstacle = ({
    size = [4,4,2,32], 
    position = [0, 0, 0], 
    color = "red",
    id,
    hasCollided = false
}) => {

    const rigidBody = useRef();
    const obstacle = useRef();
    const [scale, setScale] = useState(1);

    useFrame(() => {
        if (obstacle.current.collided == false) {
            setScale(scale + 0.1);
        }
    });
    

    return ( 
        <RigidBody 
            ref={rigidBody}
            colliders="hull"
            friction={0}
            restitution={1.3}
            type="fixed"
            position={position}
            ccd={true}
            onCollisionEnter={() => obstacle.current.collided = true}
            scale={[scale, 1, scale]}
            canSleep={false}
        >
            <mesh 
                ref={obstacle} 
                collided={hasCollided}
            >
                <cylinderGeometry args={size} />
                <meshStandardMaterial color={color} />
            </mesh>
        </RigidBody>
     );
}
 
export default Obstacle;
```

I tried multiple things like, making sure the rigid-body can't sleep, or changing the type of the rigid-body, changing the args property instead of the scale property, but nothing worked. Oh and if change the initial size of my circle, the rigid-body changes its size just fine, the problem is just when trying to change it during runtime

If anyone can tell me how I can re-render or update a Rigid-Body during runtime I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
  const [ref, api] = useRigidBody(() => ({ type: 'dynamic', position: [0, 
  2, 0], mass: 1, ...props }));
  const scale = useRef([1, 1, 1]);

  const { contactPairs } = useContactPairs();

  useEffect(() => {
  contactPairs.forEach((pair) => {
  if (pair.bodyA === api || pair.bodyB === api) {
    scale.current = scale.current.map((s) => s * 1.1);
    api.scale.set(...scale.current);
      }
    });
  }, [contactPairs, api]);
```

Here's a snippet from a previous project instead of using scale directly on rigid body mesh try this to scale the model

```
      return (
     <mesh ref={ref}>
      .......
     </mesh>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I have just seen this sorry, will try and tell you if it worked!